# Abnormal margins/spacing in my css when displayed in IE 8/9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, ie8-compatibility-mode

I recently made a website built over WordPress and in IE 8/9 I am getting a huge space in between the main body and footer.

The website is http://www.sunmarkdevelopments.com

From what I can gather, it seems like the footer menu (using a ul) is computed to having an extremely big height for some reason. At this point I'm pretty stumped as to why it's doing that. It's looks fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari and IE 7 (go figure).

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm not a pro web designer or anything so I understand my CSS is messy, sorry!

Comment: Your site's pretty clean - not a bad job on the design!

Comment: Thanks! Just started making websites seriously just over a year ago and I've noticed a major improvement over my previous work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unclosed anchor element causing a rendering error, see this line:

```
<div class="view-community"><a href="http://www.sunmarkdevelopments.com/uptown-clayton-village-phase-1/" title="Uptown Clayton I">view community<a/></div>
```

Comment: Haha wow how could I miss that?! I just use notepad++ for coding, maybe there's a plugin to detect syntax errors.

My apologies to the stack overflow community and everyone who viewed this question. Sorry for "wasting" your time with such a dumb mistake.

Also, isn't funny that IE isn't consistent even among their own browsers? lol